# To uncover results

Tags: phrases

I'm currently writing an essay and have the following paragraphs.

"We analyze NBA games from the 2000 to 2010 season, and uncover several results. First, ... . Second, ... . Third, ... ."

The [Ginger software](http://www.gingersoftware.com/grammarcheck#.WU0jFOvyu70) says it's grammatically correct. However, a friend pointed out the phrase "uncover several results" seems a little clumsy. Is there a better alternative?

Comment: You wouldn't really have results of your analysis, you'd uncover several finds, or draw several conclusions.

Comment: You might *produce* several results (*results* being something requiring work to get). With *uncover X* or *discover X*, you work to *get to* or *find* X, but it would have been someone else who *made* X. Compare: uncover a lost city vs produce a crop; discover a new species vs create a new menu.

Comment: Conclusions should be written in the past tense. This sounds like you offer the service of analyzing the data from the 2000~10 NBA seasons with the promise of uncovering more than one result, from what I'd guess would be my own criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncover implies that the results were there all along. Analyzing the data you likely determined one or more findings.  Using your judgement you determined that these findings support one or more conclusions. [findings, conclusions, and recommendations (FCR)](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/findings-conclusions-and-recommendations-FCR.html)

I was trained in the consulting process by a major US Consulting company and this process is very general. Findings imply little judgement (most people wouldn't argue your findings) and are backed up by the raw data. Conclusions require judgement but are backed by the findings. Recommendations are in turn supported by your conclusions.

So you combed the data and determined several findings. From these findings you concluded ....

Answer (score 0):

**discern**, verb, dis·cern, \di-ˈsərn, -ˈzərn\ –[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discern)

> 2:  to recognize or identify as separate and distinct
>
> 3:  to come to know or recognize mentally - *unable to discern his motives*

"We analyze NBA games from the 2000 to 2010 season, and [*discern* the results](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=discern%20the%20results%2Cuncover%20several%20results&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdiscern%20the%20results%3B%2Cc0)."

(link is an Ngram search showing little usage for mine, but zero usage for your phrase)

Comment: *We [were able to] analyze ... and discern the results.* Or, *We analyzed the games and discerned these results.*

Comment: (We were able to) [*discern the following*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=discern+the+results%2Cuncover+several+results%2Cdiscerned+the+following%2Cdiscern+the+following&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdiscern%20the%20results%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdiscerned%20the%20following%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdiscern%20the%20following%3B%2Cc0) is the colloquial phrase (added to Ngram search).

Comment: Hmm. How about "obtain several results"?

Comment: [*obtain these results*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=obtained+these+results%2Cobtain+these+results%2Cobtain+several+results%2Cobtained+several+results&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cobtained%20these%20results%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cobtain%20these%20results%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cobtain%20several%20results%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cobtained%20several%20results%3B%2Cc0), not *obtain[ed] several results*